# Add a second if statement to this script, how

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that sets a banner based on a text string inside an element. It turns out I need to set a different banner if the product is a specific one - Cisco in this case. So in the second part of the script, how can I add so the script shows another banner if the first condition is meet together with a second condition  where a text string in the header is meet, in this case "Cisco"?

The header element:

```
.productbox .head h1
```

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Approved Selection ONE"){
        $(".productbox .item .right")
          .before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner"> </span>'  );
    }
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Approved Selection" ){
        $(".productbox .item .right")
          .before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner2">    </span>' );
    }
});
```

Comment: You can combine conditions using the `&&` operator.

Comment: Ah it acts like a "and"  condition? Not sure how to write it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Approved Selection ONE"
          && $('.head h1').text().indexOf("Cisco") > -1 )
    {
        $(".productbox .item .right")
          .before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner"> </span>'  );
    }
    else if ($('span.conditionHilite').text() === "Approved Selection" ){
        $(".productbox .item .right")
          .before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner2">    </span>' );
    }
});
```

I added the second condition, you may need to modify it for your needs. Learn more about logical operators here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

**Note:** You can write the conditions in the same line, I just used a new line because of visibility.

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried in in firebug, it validates though. the header has more text than just "cisco" can that be it, does it have to be an exact match? Maybe .contains somehow would be better? Thanks! @Doodlebunch

Comment: @Xeptor If you compare `.text() === ''` it has to be an exact match. You can use `indexOf()` for this. It returns the position of some string in another string. As long as it returns an integer bigger than -1 your string is given. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: Hmm ok! how would that fit into the jquery script i have? the example you show was vanilal Js, and Im unsure how to convert the script

Comment: @Xeptor Look at me edited answer. You can use native JS the same way in jQuery context, as jQuery is nothing else then native JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = $('span.conditionHilite').text();
  var $el = $(".productbox .item .right");
  if (text === "Approved Selection ONE"){
    // do something here and then continue with the inner if
    // nested if:  
    if ($('.head h1').text() === "Cisco") {
      // do whatever you need to do when this second condition is met...
      $el.before('<span class="ciscoBanner"></span>');
    } else {
      $el.before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner"></span>'  );
    }
  } else if (text === "Approved Selection" ){
      $el.before( '<span class="myAwesomeBanner2"></span>' );
  }
});
```

Comment: no logic here in using `Nested if` , bcuz outer `if` must perform something before going into inner one

Comment: @vikrant, you could perform something first and then continue with the inner if by adding code above the inner if...

Comment: that's what I want to point out! And here there is no operation for `outer if`